# C# System.IO.Ports throws System.IO.Ports is currently only supported on Windows, but i'm currently using windows

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I am trying to communicate with an Arduino over serial.
The form is using:

```cs
using System.IO.Ports;
```

My code breaks here:

```cs
SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
```

The exception is:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'System.IO.Ports is currently only supported on Windows.

I am currently using Windows 11.

I tried reinstalling `system.io.ports`, but no success

Comment: If you only intend to use it on Windows you should set Target OS to Windows in project settings

Comment: `<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>`. Add `-windows` to the .NET version you are using in *.csproj.